# Проблема с кириллицей в DatabaseID куба SSAS 2016

Tags: sql-server, unicode, olap, integration-services

Есть куб, в котором идентификатор БД и некоторые измерения названы по-русски. В SSIS + SSAS 2008 (Windows 2008 R2) всё нормально обрабатывалось через dts-пакет. Попробовал перенести это на SQL 2016 SP1 CU3 (Windows 2012 R2). При запуске пакета из Visual Studio Integrated Shell на сервере SSIS тоже всё в порядке. После деплоя в SSIS Storage и запуске оттуда выдаёт ошибку:

> Ошибки в диспетчере метаданных. Либо database с идентификатором "Р‘Р°Р»Р°РЅСЃРѕРІР°СЏ" не существует в server с идентификатором "DBOLAP", либо у пользователя нет разрешений для доступа к этому объекту.

Так же ругается и на измерения. Явно ошибка с юникодом, но не могу понять где. Локаль на серверах вроде везде поставил русскую.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Установил CU4. Залил dtsx с целевым 2016, потом поменял на vNext и залил снова. Работает.